# A question from the famous quote of AGT golden buzzer Nightbirde

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence, conjunctions

I watched a very touching video on youtube recently and there was a very beautiful quote:
"You can’t wait until life isn’t hard anymore before you decide to be happy" by Nightbirde.

What confuses me is the conjunction "before" in the sentence. I think she means "you ought to be happy before life isn't hard anymore". Here she uses "can't wait...until" and that is a kind of time concept to my understanding. So, I would use "and" or "then" to replace the "before".

I would like to know your thoughts about the conjunction here.
Thank you!

Comment: Rough analogies: *I won't wait until I get hungry before I eat.* (I will eat before I get hungry.) ... *I won’t wait until life is easy before I decide to be happy.* (I will decide to be happy before life is easy.)

Comment: It is a time concept but there's nothing wrong with using _until_ with _before_ in this way. It's a bit like being on a road trip and saying "I'll wait until I get to Baton Rouge before I eat", you could express it as "I'll wait until I get to Baton Rouge and then I'll eat" or "I'll not eat before I get to Baton Rouge" but the combination is quite normal. The only thing I would change in Nightbirde's statement is her use of _can't_, I'd prefer _mustn't_ myself as you _can_ do it but it's not a good idea.